# Is there a way to link a phrase to a number in Microsoft Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

As title says, I want to know if there is a way to have a user generate phrase link to a number, say in cell A2 the user inputs 'cat', which I want to represent the number 4, is there a way to make cell A3 work with '=A2*2' and have it display 8?

Comment: If you have a table of phrases and numbers then you can use VLOOKUP to convert the phrase to a number.  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,THETABLE,2,FALSE)*2,"Phrase?")`  where THETABLE is a named range with your lookups

Comment: Sweet, it works thanks!